# Glued grip has rotated, won't rotate back

Tags: handlebars, grips

The leather-like grips on my cruiser have rotated a bit over the last year and a half; the faux "stitching" on one of them is now at a location that feels weird when I'm holding it. I can't rotate the grip back by hand.

How can I loosen the adhesive enough that I can rotate the grip back to the correct position, without removing it?

Comment: My grips are normally unmovable, but cycling in heavy rain for a few hours loosen's them right up. I hesitate to say take your handlebars off and soak them in a sink, so this is just a comment...

Comment: Well, I agree. If it is leather i stretches when wheat. When it dries it will tighten again.

Comment: It's a thin layer of leather-like material over a hard plastic grip.

Comment: I'd just remove the unglued faux-leather all together and glue new grips made of real leather.

Comment: @Tadeusz: If I had the money, I'd do the same. Alas, this is what came with the bike. If I replaced these, I'd replace them with bolt-on grips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems a bit unusual to me that your grip would be actually 'glued' to your handlebar. Typically grips hold themselves in place, but I'll take your word for it. =]

If your grip is in fact 'glued' in place, the adhesive is likely mediocre quality, and rotation you're experiencing is due to heat from your hand and/or the outdoors slightly softening the glue.

You may be able to un-rotate the grip by heating it with a hair-dryer, and therefore softening the adhesive to a point where you can move it by hand. Be careful not to burn or melt the synthetic leather, though!

Comment: I've had grips that were glued onto other bikes. Perhaps "glue" is the incorrect word, I don't know. A glued rose by any other name would be just as sticky.

Comment: The hairdryer softened the adhesive between the grip and the fake leather cover, enough that I could turn it back to its proper location. Thanks!