# How do I put grips on mountain bike handlebars?

Tags: mountain-bike, handlebars, grips

I just spent the last 10 minutes trying to put a new set of grips on to my mountain bike handlebars..

The old ones came off fairly agreeably and I've got the new ones 80-90% of the way on, however, at this point both my hands are stinging from the aggressive twisting and pushing - I have tried gloves, but I feel it's best left till my hands don't hurt anymore.

Is there a tried and tested way of doing this? Or is there a knack to this that I am missing?

Comment: Related: [Glued grip has rotated, won't rotate back](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/320/glued-grip-has-rotated-wont-rotate-back)

Comment: Every bike mechanic, shade tree and pro, has his own unique and secret way, from air to soap to hairspray to WD40.

Comment: (It should be noted that there is available (though I don't know from where) a grip glue, used for exercise equipment.  Costs something $75 for about 16 oz of the stuff, according to the repair guy at my gym, but a little goes a long way.)

Comment: There's a similar product for motocross grips with is significantly less expensive. Slidy when it's wet and glue when it's dry. Check a motorcycle store if you have one near.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I didn't have any of your suggestions so I pulled out my eucalyptus oil and gave that a try. It worked great, better when I left the end plug in place to hold the oil inside the grip.

Comment: @DanielRHicks What are the grips made of? I'd be very wary of putting aggressive organic solvents like WD-40 or hairspray anywhere near a plastic or rubber product.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Modern handgrips are generally made of a fairly robust plastic or synthetic rubber.  Anything that's wimpy wouldn't stand up to sweat and body oils.

Comment: Aren't most grips fixed by a screw? Mine certainly are. The exchange was extremely easy.

Comment: @VladimirF Lock on grips are yes. other brands are available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spit.

Im not kidding. Saliva is a great lubricant that will dry with little residue, and depending on any sugars in your system, could be a little tacky. I have done this for years.

Comment: Certainly seems like a cheap solution.

Comment: I agree it is not the most elegant of solutions. But cheap, easy and works.

Comment: -1 for throttle grip

Comment: No throttle grip - I didn't open up a gland an poor it in, just a little bit inside the grip.

Comment: @Wezly there was throttle grip, you just didn't test it soon(or hard) enough :) it's not like the lube instantly evaporated once the grip was in place.

Comment: @dotjoe I assumed throttle grip was a lasting effect where the grip constantly rotates after application - not only momentary whilst fitting the grip, after all, some rotation is needed to get the grip on there in the first place.

Answer (score 19):

Two solutions I've used:

1. Spray the inside of the grip with hair spray. Slide it on immediately, and then when the hair spray dries, it will glue the grip in place.
2. Use rubbing alcohol. It does not do as good of a job at locking the grip in place, but it does evaporate quickly and doesn't leave any lubricant inside the grip.

Comment: +1 Hairspray is the best. The higher the the alcohol content the better. As in, use the cheap stuff. Aqua Net, in the big pink can works excellently.

Comment: I'm guessing this will still allow the grips to be removed? eventually?

Comment: To remove you just use hairspray again.

Comment: Rubbing alcohol is my favorite. it dries fast and doesn't leave much residue. it makes it possible to remove the grips without damage in many cases.

Comment: I prefer hairspray because the grips tend to stay in place after the hairspray has dried. I had a friend tell me Aqua Net, too; evidently there _is_ a difference.

Comment: Aqua Net is also good for spud launchers, in case you have one mounted on your bike, now it can have two functions.

Comment: OMG! this worked great. I have been riding around for 2 mos annoyed that my grips were sliding off and planning on getting to a bike store so they could use air to get them back on...but this quick fix helped in 2 min.
THANKS!!!!!

Comment: Rave Mega Hold. It is literally cheaper than isopropyl alcohol. http://lowesfoods.grocerydirect.com/pd/Rave/Hair-Spray-Mega-Hold-3/7-fl-oz/305213360003/

Comment: Hairspray works amazingly well for this, and it's cheap. You should be able to find a bottle of low-end stuff for around $2, maybe less at a dollar store.

Answer (score 11):

Distribute thin zip-ties around the inside of the grip somewhat evenly so that they provide slippery "rails" on which the grip can slide on the bar. Once the grip is in place, pull the zip-ties out (with pliers if necessary).

Comment: Interesting idea, may try this for lack of spit/hair spray.

Comment: +1 best way if you don't have an air compressor. You'll need pliers to get them out. Anything using a lubricant means you'll have throttle grip for some period of time.

Comment: By the gods! It worked! It worked!

Answer (score 10):

Best solution (probably available only at shops): use an air compressor with a narrow tip to inject air between the grip and the handlebar at an angle (like spiralling around). This will create an air cushion and you can move the grip around (keep moving the air jet as you apply the air jet, since only in some positions the air cushion is formed).

Less professional method is what I use to do at home:

1. Wash bar and grip perfectly, with water and soap, to remove grease (even the grease from your hands). If the grip is new, probably not needed.
2. Spill like a small spoon of alcohol inside the grip, and shake it inside a bit to make all the inner side of the grip wet with alcohol.
3. Quickly (before the alcohol evaporates), insert the grip, twisting and pulling.
4. In case it gets harder from the middle to the end of insertion, two strategies might help:

   1. Push from the bottom (lateral part) of the grip, so as to "fatten" it in a barrel shape. This increases its inner diameter, allowing it to snap into position.
   2. Pull from the inner border, like you would pull a sock around your foot, preferrably with both hands.

I am eager to know other alternatives, because this not always work. Specifically, it might take a few days untill the alcohol eventually disapears. Before that, some slight slipping might happen, but usually nothing serious.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is why I prefer locking grips.

Comment: Hockey tape!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Avenir 3D rubber grips on my cruiser bar: Vodka :)  Just a ***splash*** inside the grips, wriggle them on, and let excess drain outside the end hole.

Comment: Will the 60% water be safe (not a rust hazard) for all metals/coatings?

Answer (score 4):

Since no one else mentioned this:  I always use a glass/window cleaner (like Windex).

It works really well.  Easy to spray on the bar or in the grip and it evaporates quickly but not as quickly as isopropyl alcohol.  Plus I think it has a surfactant which makes things slide a bit easier.  And you may be likely to have some around.

Usually works to take old ones off too, slip something like a screwdriver into the end to make a space, spray some in, then twist/wiggle it.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Thank you for your well-formed contribution.

Comment: I use this method too. Works very well, and is generally available.

Answer (score 3):

I always used hairspray with my grips, it's the best solution in my opinion. It not only keeps them from slipping too far on/off the handlebars, but keeps them from twisting in place. Now, however, I use locking grips like these: http://www.ebay.com/itm/110736653646?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649#ht_1030wt_1163

Answer (score 2):

Two parts to this question - how to ease off an old grip that you may want to reuse (ie cutting it off is too destructive.  Followed by how to fit the new one.

I use a thin old electrician's flathead screwdriver to gently lever the edge off the grip up, then tilt the bike so that it leans to the side I'm working on, and then squirt a splash of water and dishwash liquid from a spray bottle into the raised edge.   Then withdraw the screwdriver and work the grip around.  You can feel it loosen and then it just comes off.

To fit the new one, you simply push it on and position the angle before the soapy water dries.

Once the water evaporates the dishwash is left behind, providing somewhat of a tacky adhesive.   So yes this will leave it slidey for an hour or so while the water dries.  You can speed this by leaving the bike in the sunlight, black/dark grips should dry quickly.

Personally I'm a big fan of the grips with palm support, but you need them tilted to the right angle before the soap dries.  Then tighten the tiny restraining bolts that many new grips have now.

Answer (score 1):

To put simple rubber compound grips I usually use two step procedure. Use extreme degreaser on handlebar, the one that is used to degrease car brake rotors. Then pour some water into grips and then put them on while water is still inside grips.
To take them off it's even simplier. I use syringe with water. Stick the needle through grip up until the surface of a handlebar and then inject some water. The grip come off with no effort at all.
Using lock-on grips though makes process of putting grips on and off a lot easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

The technique I use is to apply dish washing soap to the metal of the grip so that they are slick and put the grips in boiled water. Leave the water to cool down enough to put your hands in but so that the grips are still warm. The water will cause the grips to expand so that they go on easy, they will shrink back down when they cool. Then simply put the grips on using the usual twist and push method.

Comment: Things that aren't metal really don't expand very much when they're heated to the sort of temperatures that you can handle. If the heating has any relevance other than psychological, it's probably because warming rubber makes it more supple.

Answer (score 1):

**How to remove the old grip first**

In case you have old grips already on, or want to adjust existing ones, I'll just give a more precise version of the "rubbing alcohol" suggestion from https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8720/34651

What I have been using is the Servisol IPA 170 isopropyl alcohol. It even comes with a little plastic tube that fits perfectly with this application, because you have to insert it in below the existing grip somehow! Here's a sample Amazon link: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000KHDYB0

I then first start to stick a spoon under the grip to make room for the little tube, then put the tube in, spray some in, then push the spoon further a bit more, spray again and then my grip comes off. Here I used an aluminium spoon, but if it weren't my bicycle I would try and use some hard plastic or wood to avoid scratching the handlebar. Not that it matters much as it will be under the grip afterwards.

The thing dries off quite quickly, and the grip soon becomes firmly placed again.

Placing a new grip would be the same but you wouldn't need the spoon, just spray over the surface directly.

Here's a photo of the product and the start of the procedure mentioned. I wish I could have done a video, but a third hand was missing :-)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hairspray, Hairspray, Hairspray. Lubricant on the way on. Adhesive once dry. Ive done literally thousands of grips with hairspray in 25 years in bike shops and team maintenance. Never has one come off when nor required or squirmed.

Comment: You're totally right, but this was already suggested in another answer from 2012.   Best to up-vote that answer so it rises to the top, and can comment on that answer with more info.   Have a browse through the SE [tour] to see how this site is a lot different to the average chatty web-forum.   I'm picking that you have a bunch of experience which is always welcome, so do have a go at some of the unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a can of Aerosol Lubricant with a spray nozzle. When it comes to reinstalling the [handlebar grip](https://www.bikeshepherd.org/how-to-remove-bike-handle-grips/) to the bike, the process becomes much easier compared to the removal process. You can simply place it over the edge of the handlebar and make sure to target the hole of the grip at the center of the handlebar. Then use your palm to push and hammer it the rest of the way until the handlebar is in the right position.

Comment: Wouldn't the lubricant persist, or at least evaporate very slowly?  This might make for a grip that slides/rotates under pressure, no?

Answer (score -3):

Boiling water helped but hair spray was best

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on this site. Please consider expanding your answer to include how you used boiling water and hairspray to aid in the process.